# Convergence of a subseries of the series $\sum_{n \ge 1} \frac{1}{p_n}$, where $p_n$ is the $n$ th prime.

Tags: divergent-series

Let $p_n$ be the $n$th prime number. Does the following series 
$$ \sum_{n \ge 1} \frac{1}{p_{p_n}} = \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{5} + \frac{1}{11} + \cdots $$ converge or diverge?
Similarly, I am so curious about the convergence of the subsequent type of subserious, like $$ \sum_{n \ge 1} \frac{1}{p_{p_{p_n}}} $$, and so on.

Comment: I am sure it is a duplicate, $\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{p_{p_n}}$ is already convergent.

Comment: That just follows from proving that $p_{p_n}\gg n\log^2 n$, then applying Cauchy's condensation test.

Comment: Oh, really! How about the next question?

Comment: If $\frac{1}{p_{p_n}}$ is summable also $\frac{1}{p_{p_{p_n}}}$ is summable (it is a subsequence).

Comment: How can we prove that $p_{p_n}\gg n\log^2 n$?

Comment: From the PNT (or the Chebyshev's bound) we have $\pi(n)\ll\frac{n}{\log n}$, hence $p_n\gg n\log n$ and $p_{p_n}\gg n\log^2 n$.